# JQuery keep class for selected menu

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have the following menu on a header.php page that is included on each link page as follows:

```
<nav id="main-nav">
    <ul class="container_12">
        <li>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="home.php"><? echo TEXT_DASHBOARD_HOME;?></a></li>
                        <li><a href="plans.php"><? echo TEXT_DASHBOARD_PLAN;?></a></li>
            <li><a href="voucher.php"><? echo TEXT_DASHBOARD_VOUCH;?></a></li>
         </ul>
        </li>   
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Now when I click on any menu item I execute the following code contained on header.php:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('nav > ul > li > ul > li').addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');
});
```

and it works as soon as I stay on the same page, as soon as I click on another menu and I get redirected to another page and the class gets removed, how can I pass a variable of the `li.index()` that was clicked and add class to that specific `<li>`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

for your specific solution:

Since a new page is being loaded can we just set the current class to that specific page item if we already know which is loading...

and for your solution using jquery also:

you should atleast  either know it by its position or any relative identity for selecting it...
like: 
if page is home then add current to home li
if page is ... and so on and so on...